# System no longer recognises I have two monitors and is forced to 720p

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've been using Ubuntu on my desktop for a few weeks with two Dell P2417H 1080p monitors connected to a GeForce 1050ti GPU, one via HDMI and the other via Display Port. I booted my machine today; only the Display Port has an image and it is set to 720p. In the settings menu it is recorded as an Unknown monitor.
I checked Software Updates and a swathe of updates were installed with no change to the issue. Under additional drivers it is correctly showing the GeForce 1050ti and is using the Nvidia metepackage driver 535 (proprietary, tested). I have disconnected/reconnected the monitors and rebooted the system.

Comment: `xrandr -q` should show all connected monitors. You may want to look at the output, and perhaps let us see it as well.

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*

Comment: Someone else suggested I rollback the driver and I've done that to the 525 version which seems to have fixed it